# E: Unable to locate package wget in docker

Tags: docker, debian, apt

I am trying to build the following dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN apt-get update
# because apparently composer can shell out to unzip? Who knew...
RUN apt-get install wget unzip zip -y
```

but it failed with the following error

```
[root@dev svc]# docker build -t wsb -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 17.62 MB
Step 1/11 : FROM php:8.0-apache
 ---> 97f22a92e1d1
Step 2/11 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ddba6cf13bac
Step 3/11 : RUN apt-get install wget unzip zip -y
 ---> Running in 6fb3e2f37401
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package wget
E: Unable to locate package unzip
E: Unable to locate package zip
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install wget unzip zip -y' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Existing contents of sources.list file

```
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20210511T000000Z buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20210511T000000Z buster/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20210511T000000Z buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

I am not sure why it's unable to find.  Should I add any URL to /etc/apt/sources.list to get this working?

**EDIT**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 17.62 MB
Step 1/9 : FROM php:8.0-apache
 ---> 97f22a92e1d1
Step 2/9 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install wget unzip zip -y
 ---> Running in 374b1060dfb3

Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to programming? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 11):

You've cached a stale update so apt is trying to install these packages from versions that are no longer in the repositories. This is why [Docker's best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) mention to not separate these steps:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install wget unzip zip -y
```

---

From the second issue you are now seeing, you have a networking issue within your containers. There are lots of possible causes, including the host not being connected to the network, and networking changing after the docker engine was started. You'd need to provide a lot more debugging (can you reach these nodes from the host, is DNS working, is there a proxy or firewall on the network, etc).

Comment: Thanks for answering but it does not work.  I updated the output under the EDIT section.